# how to add Label text to JQuery Mobile Slider

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to add labels such as low, middle ,high,highest to the slider input on Jquery mobile.
Or is there another slider that has this functionality?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @frictionlesspulley I was expecting there is some configuration that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

I think that example here can help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/cUNyr/1/

```
$.fn.extend({
    sliderLabels: function(left,right) {
        var $this = $(this); 
        var $sliderdiv= $this.next("div.ui-slider[role='application']");
        $sliderdiv
        .css({'font-weight': 'normal'}); 
        $sliderdiv
        .prepend('<span class="ui-slider-inner-label"  style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:20px;">'+left+ '</span>')
        .append('<span class="ui-slider-inner-label" style="position: absolute; right:0px; top:20px;">'+right+ '</span>');         
    }
});

$('#slider').sliderLabels('LEFT','RIGHT');​
```